# Multi purpose TypeScript decorator

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

I’m trying to define a decorator that could be used on a class as well as on a property. The code works, but I can’t make the type definitions work. I currently have the following:

```
type Decorator<T> = T extends Function
  ? (target: T) => T
  : (target: T, propertyKey: string) => void;

function Schema<T>(): Decorator<T> {
  return (target: T, propertyKey?: string) => {
    if (target instanceof Function) {
      return target;
    }
  };
}

@Schema()
export default class MyClass {
  @Schema()
  bool: boolean;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&target=99&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDGB7ATgQ2CgPAFQHxQF4psoIAPYCAOwBMBnKAMQFcr5gBLRKgWACgoUAPxQAFMFTIA5hGAAuYgEpC+bP0ELxkmfOIAaKGGSJIyUAGkIIBXWDIOVKcoL4Abog40A3P34AzVnYuKigAZXgACwgAW1QcXFFFBTgkNAxkeKgAb3UoZFlmZBCtaVkFbAMjEwgzEEsQIRs7BycVbNzBDj8xCVLgKAdbVDYIRG6WNk5uZRyBQXn84EKQ3p0fOcEAX1zN9e2+fgABcKjYxP5yMBR+mgg-VGYAG374R9Q6BgBZEABhN4-2nNjpEYqhznMAEaIRCPBRQmEQYZ7fhAA)

If I explicitly use set the generic `T` to `typeof BooleanProperty`, it works. However, I want Typescript to be able to infer the type and stop complaining.

I also tried other options, such as function overloading, but without any success.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want your decorator factory to be non-generic, and have it produce a generic decorator.  Right now your decorator factory is generic and returns a non-generic decorator.  It's the difference between these two:

```
// bad
declare const genericFactoryForSpecificFunction: <T>() => (x: T) => T;
const oops = genericFactoryForSpecificFunction()(123); // unknown

// good
declare const specificFactoryForGenericFunction: () => <T>(x: T) => T;
const okay = specificFactoryForGenericFunction()(123); // 123
```

In the bad case, the compiler has to infer `T` when you call `genericFactoryForSpecificFunction()`, but there's no value of type `T` for it to consult in that expression.  So it picks `unknown`, meaning that the subsequent call on the argument `123` returns `unknown`.  In the good case, the compiler defers inference of `T` until the call to the function returned by `specificFactoryForGenericFunction()`.  That lets the compiler actually use a value of type `T` to infer `T`, and so you get `123` out.

---

Once you make this change, you will need your `Decorator` type to be a specific type that represents a generic function call signature.  I suppose it's possible to translate your conditional type to that form, but it's a bit messy and uses rest tuples:

```
type PossibleDecorator = <T>(
  target: T,
  ...args: T extends Function ? [] : [string?]
) => T extends Function ? T : void;

declare const pd: PossibleDecorator;
pd(RegExp); // okay, class decorator
pd({a: ""}, "a") // okay, prop decorator
pd(RegExp, "oops"); // error, tried to pass prop to class decorator
```

I'd say that a multi-call-signature overload would be nicer and it has the same behavior:

```
type Decorator = {
  <T extends new (...args: any) => any>(ctor: T): T; // class decorator
  <T, K extends keyof T>(proto: T, member: K): void; // prop decorator
}

declare const d: Decorator;
d(RegExp); // okay, class decorator
d({ a: "" }, "a") // okay, prop decorator
d(RegExp, "oops"); // error, tried to pass prop to class decorator
```

---

So, your example code would then become something like this:

```
function Schema(): Decorator {
  return (target: any, propertyKey?: string) => {
    if (target instanceof Function) {
      return target;
    }
    return;
  };
}

@Schema()
export default class MyClass {
  @Schema()
  bool: boolean = false;
}
```

Looks good.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true&target=99#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3mgDuAlgGb5gBiUYGSMAnqdQOIgogwmkCuKl+qAXPAAUASngBeAHzwAPABUJggB4DZoyfFkBuALAAoZOixIA1lBrjseMEXYUqtejCYs2ZLj1QjBARgBMAZmFNeAB6EPg-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-Dg1BYKAhBQBwEBYJ+8AALI0AAwgqbT6S51G0SILw7M0EACClSD7DWFgBRAaAgA5ehAA)